# Undesired shadow in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data for school project. However an ugly shadow appears when I do so. I have no clue of what it can be.

Here is my code:

```
index_labels = np.empty(len(smoothed), dtype=object)
for i in range(len(index_labels)):
    index_labels[i] = ""
    if i%365 == 0:
        index_labels[i] = 2015 + int(i//365)

plt.scatter(smoothed.index, smoothed.national, label='PV load factor rolling mean over 24h.')
plt.plot(smoothed.index, sin_ref, color='red', label='Sinusoidal reference')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(index_labels)
# plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and here is the different variables used so you have an idea:

[image]

and a zoom on the plot :

[image]

Thanks to all of you! Greetings :)

Comment: That looks like thousands of ticks side-by-side. Probably worth looking at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html, instead of your current approach to creating `index_labels`.

Comment: With the line drop the problem is that the original x is crowded of values which create a second black line as follow: https://imgur.com/a/6xTGC4Q

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you :) Wanna answer the question or do I ?

Comment: Feel free to self-answer!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Solution from @BigBen:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

plt.scatter(smoothed.index, smoothed.national, label='PV load factor rolling mean over 24h.')
plt.plot(smoothed.index, sin_ref, color='red', label='Sinusoidal reference')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(730))
plt.show()
```

Multiple has a very good name: it only shows the label for the multiple of n.

[image]

EDIT: as find later, matplotlib do auto axis labeling for dates. Only problem was that column was recognized as string. pandas.to_datetime allow you to convert it back to pandas datetime type.